# GeoServer native vs declared SRS & SRS handling

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

I am seeking guidance regarding layer [CRS](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#coordinate-reference-systems) settings on GeoServer.

After researching various discussions on Stack Overflow, it appears that a common recommendation is to store data in EPSG 4326 as it is unprojected (correct me if I am wrong). Suppose, for instance, my data is stored in 4326, and on the client side, I want to display it on a web map in 900913/3857 (with GeoWebCache being seeded in 900913/3857). When adding the data as a layer on GeoServer, GeoServer automatically detects the Native SRS as 4326.

Should I set the 'Declared SRS' to 900913/3587, or is it advisable to keep it as 4326? Furthermore, in the layers settings, is it recommended to maintain the SRS handling as 'Forced Declared' or opt for 'Reproject native to declared'? This is probably a very common scenario, but I can't quite decide the best method to optimize the Geoserver layer CRS settings.

Any insights or advice on optimizing these GeoServer layer CRS settings for this scenario?

[image]

[image]

Comment: EPSG:4326 is georeferenced but not s.s. projected.